# What class is this micro SD card?

Tags: speed, micro-sd-card

I had a 2GB Sandisk micro SD card lying around but no number written on it.

My digital camera's card just died and it recommends a Class 10 card.

I bench-marked the micro SD card and this is what I got.

[image: FAT16]

[image: FAT32]

Is this an overperforming Class 6 card or underperforming Class 10?

Comment: Could be a class 8...

Answer (score 1):

Since it never gets up to 10 MB/s, that should make it a class 6. Try some photos with it. If I'm right, all it will affect is the time between shots while it's writing to the card.

Comment: What about a Class 8 (never noticed them being sold though)

Comment: Never heard of a class 8 for sale. I don't believe they exist.